# Maximize profit

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My book (George F. Simmons - Calculus with analitic geometri) hasthe following question:

An library could buy from the book publisher the book "Rituals" with a cost of $40.0$ each. The manager from the library estimate that could sell $180$ units of the books with a price of $100.0$ and each reduction of $5.0$ on the price will increase will increase $30$ books on the sales. What would be the price of the book to maximize the total profit?

I've found the following formula of the profit:

$P = (60 - 5x)*(180 + 30x)$

To maximize the profit I need a derivative to get the critical point.

$\dfrac{d((60 - 5x)*(180 + 30x))}{dx}$

Then, the derivative is: $dP/dx = 900 - 300x$

The critical point lies on $x = 3$ where the book will be sold by $45.0$. He got the answer $= 8.5$.

I don't know if the book is wrong or my idea is wrong. I've got attention to the fact the problem is wrong because he do not told if all the $180$ book $= 100$ or each exemplar at cost of $100$. So I considered each book is $100.0$.

Someone may help please? Thank you.

Comment: The $3$ is correct. That's $15$ dollars less than $\$100$ per book, so the selling price is $\$85$. The *profit* is $45$ per book, but that's not what was asked.

Comment: Ok thank you, sorry for misstake. I was just confused with the answer the book guive me.

Comment: You are welcome. Minor slip, the work was right.

Comment: wooow... It is true. I have confused. '-'